# laravel eloquent trouble matching multi-word table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I love Eloquent so much when it's working! But this time I'm adding a table with a two-word name, and I have something wrong that I just don't see yet...

I already have a Person object/people table, with other entities having a one-to-many relationship working already.  Now I'm adding the concept of audio files that can feature multiple people.  I've added two tables for this:

- **audio_files** (with auto id, filename, summary, timestamps)
- **audio_file_person** (with auto id, audio_file_id and person_id)

Then I have AudioFile.php:

```
class AudioFile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'filename', 'summary', 'recording_date'
    ];

    public function people()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person'); 
    }

    public function getPersonListAttribute()
    {
        return $this->people->lists('id')->all();
    }

}
```

And I've updated Person.php with this:

```
public function audio_files()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\AudioFile')->withTimestamps();
}

public function getAudioFileListAttribute()
{
    return $this->audio_files->lists('id')->all();
}
```

Using the same pattern I've used for other records that people are associated with, in the person's view I'm checking to see if there are any audio files to show:

```
@unless ($subject->audio_files->isEmpty())
    <div>
        <h4>Audio links: </h4>
        @foreach($subject->audio_files as $audio)
            @include ('audio.partials.audio_link', ['audio' => $audio])
        @endforeach
        <br/>
    </div>
@endunless
```

However, this seems to be empty for people where I do have audio_file_person records for them.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or where else I should be checking? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Add `protected $table = 'audio_file_person';` property to the `Person` model.

Comment: thanks, Lado! I've added this line into the early part of my Person class, and now when I load the page that exercises it, I get a big "NotFoundHttpException in Router.php line 960".  (In the past I think this error meant I needed to add a 'use' statement up at the top, but in this case I don't actually have a AudioFilePerson.php class; I don't usually make one for pivot tables).  Any ideas/recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Try indicating the pivot table in the belongsToMany relationship.

In your Person model:

```
public function audio_files()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(AudioFile::class, 'audio_file_person', 'person_id', 'audio_file_id');
}
```

In your AudioFile model:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'audio_file_person', 'audio_file_id', 'person_id');
}
```

For the audio_file_person table, I usually don't include an incremented id on a pivot table, but it shouldn't really pose a problem.

**Update 1:**

In the view:

```
@foreach($people as $person)
    {{$person->name}}: <br>
    @unless ($person->audio_files->isEmpty())
      <ul>
      @foreach($person->audio_files as $audio_file)
        <li>{{$audio_file->filename}}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endunless
@endforeach
```

**Update 2:**

In your project root:

`> php artisan tinker`
`> use App\Person` (or namespace of your `Person` model)
`> $person = Person::find(1)` (an id that you've set up in the pivot table)
`> $person->audio_files`

Comment: thanks, #yan_n! I added this in, but still no luck yet; a person who has an associated audio file still doesn't show any records :(

Comment: @DianeKaplan how are you associating a person to the audio file? Manually adding an entry to the pivot table? or with `$person->audio_files()->attach($audio_file_id)`?

Comment: I've been manually adding entries to the pivot table (have done this in the past with other things associated with people and it had worked)

Comment: @DianeKaplan Alright, maybe the problem comes from the part with `[loop thru and show links]` ? I updated my answer with a snippet just to see if you have something in the same vein.  
Also, how are you using `getAudioFileListAttribute`? And which version of Laravel are you using? In recent versions, `lists` has been replaced by `pluck`.

Comment: Sadly I can tell it's evaluating to empty because the first thing I try to do for any records is show a heading. I've added the code above for completeness

Comment: How about the controller? Any manipulation on the `$subject`?

Comment: To eliminate problems from the view and controller, maybe try using tinker to see if the relations load correctly. See update

Comment: thanks for all your help, @yan_n!  Yes tinker was also showing that they weren't connected either :(  I want to get the two-word table done correctly, but I need to timebox how much I'm willing to spend just to have this called audio_files rather than audiofiles (don't like because of confusion sounding like audiophile).  I'm running out of time and need to wrap this up, so I've just redone it as audiofiles and audiofile_person, and got it working lickety split. Thanks for all your ideas and assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you error is unable to get the table name as per the model, you have to declare the table property in your model as

```
protected $table = 'audio_file_person';
```

so it will take the custom table name not by using plural version of the model name

Comment: thanks #msonowal! I don't actually have an error message (just a lack of records showing up), but I've tried adding this line into the early part of my Person class.  Now when I load the page that exercises it, I get a big "NotFoundHttpException in Router.php line 960".  (In the past I think this error meant I needed to add a 'use' statement up at the top, but in this case I don't actually have a AudioFilePerson.php class; I don't usually make one for pivot tables).  Any ideas/recommendations?